# Average of the same cell from different worksheets in the same workbook using openpyxl

Tags: excel, average, openpyxl

I have a workbook with 27 sheets named "Sensor Status" "Sensor Status (1)" and so on there is 1 sheet named "Sheet1". In each sheet (except "Sheet1") cell I4 contains a number. How can I use openpyxl to get the average of all the I4's and put the result into "Sheet1"?? This process will get repeated each quarter and the total amount of sheets will vary so using the exact names of each sheet in the script is not an option in the answer unfortunately.

Comment: Just get the value of each cell and then do mean() from statistics?

Comment: I am trying to get the average of all the I3's from all the workbooks and do the same for the I4's not the average of I3 and I4.

Comment: Yes, get the values from all workbooks and then apply average. Fill a list or dictionary with your values from the workbooks.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, I am very new to Python. Could you help me out?

Comment: For example:```my_values = [] my_values.append( sheet['I4'].value)```

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try.